# Can i pass (*ptr) to a function which is taking reference as argument

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct x{
    vector<int> y;
};
void magic(struct x& d)
{
    d.y[0] = 5;
}
int main() {
    struct x d;
    d.y = {1,2,3};

    struct x* z = &d;
    magic(*z);

    cout<<z->y[0];
    return 0;
}
```

Is this code valid and how? Can we pass *z to a function which requires c++ reference.

Comment: The function takes a reference to `x`, and you are passing it an `x`. This is similar to `x &d= *z;`. Why do you expect this to not work?

Comment: ...or more generally, why should there be any difference between `d` and `*z` ?

Comment: In C, you need to do `struct x d;`.  In C++, you only need to do `x d;`.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - [No, no, no](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058), don't *ever* do that.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer `z` points to the object `d`.

```
struct x* z = &d;
```

Dereferencing the pointer you get the lvalue of the object d that is passed as an argument to the function by reference

```
magic(*z);
```

So there is no magic.

In fact these two calls

```
magic( *z );
```

and

```
magic( d );
```

are equivalent. The only difference is that in the first call there is used a more complicated expression.